# Spectrum of irreducible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonnegative-matrices

The Wikipedia article on the [Perron-Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Non-negative_matrices) theorem claims that (without referencing a proper proof):

> The key feature of theory in the non-negative case is to find some special subclass of non-negative matrices— irreducible matrices— for which a non-trivial generalization is possible. **Namely, although the eigenvalues attaining the maximal absolute value may not be unique, the structure of maximal eigenvalues is under control: they have the form $e^{i2πl/h}r$, where $h$ is an integer called the period of matrix, $r$ is a real strictly positive eigenvalue, and $l = 0, 1, ..., h − 1$.**

I have trouble constructing a proof for this and my literature research has unfortunately not been helpful so far.

**UPDATE**: Does this also hold for all eigenvalues? (and not only for the maximum modulus ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most treatises that cover Perron-Frobenius theorem for nonnegative matrices should contain the relevant proofs. In particular, proofs can be found in vol. 2 of Gantmacher's *"The Theory of Matrices"* or Horn and Johnson's *"Matrix Analysis"*.

Comment: _Corollary 8.4.6_ (c) in Horn & Johnson states that all eigenvalues with maximum modulus have the form $e^{i2\pi/h}r$, but I would like to prove a stronger formulation that requires that *all* eigenvalues (i.e. not only the maximum modulus ones) satisfy the property.

Comment: @LennartVanderGoten What you want to prove cannot be true in general (and this isn't what the Wikipedia entry says, if that matters), because it suggests that all eigenvalues of an irreducible matrix have the same moduli.